# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro fecha con fetchall? DJANGO

Tags: django

Mi cuestión viene debida a que hago un cursor.fetchall() y me devuelve rows, el problema es que no sé como hacer un filtro sin tener un model es decir yo solo hago una consulta pero me gustaria filtrar la fecha, ¿alguna idea?

Antes tenia esto:

```
   if is_valid_queryparam(date_min):
    qs = qs.filter(prog_data_ini__gte=date_min)

if is_valid_queryparam(date_max):
    qs = qs.filter(prog_data_ini__lt=date_max)
```

Me funcionaba el problema es que venia del model pero ahora al ser una consulta externa el qs.filter no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas directamente ese tipo de consultas debes filtrar antes de realizar el fetch, te dejo un ejemplo :

```
# primero filtramos
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_qs WHERE prog_data_ini >= '" + date_min + "' AND prog_data_ini <= '" + date_max + "'")
# luego hacemos el fetch
row = cursor.fetchall()
```